# Group by using LIKE Operator and ignore NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, sql-like

I have written one query to group the tax items, if tax is null, i dont want to display the tax name. How to do this? Please check my sql server statement:

```
 SELECT     
   'CENTRAL EXCISE DUTY'    AS 'TaxName',
   SUM(TaxAmount)       AS 'Tax'
 FROM
   PMT_InvoiceTaxAttribute
 WHERE 
   InvoiceID = 100 
   AND TaxAttributeName NOT LIKE '%IBR%' 
   AND TaxAttributeName NOT LIKE '%CST%' 
   AND TaxAttributeName NOT LIKE '%VAT%'
 UNION
 SELECT
   'CST'            AS 'TaxName',
   SUM(TaxAmount)       AS 'Tax'
 FROM
   PMT_InvoiceTaxAttribute
 WHERE 
   InvoiceID = 100   
   AND TaxAttributeName LIKE '%CST%'
 UNION
 SELECT
   'VAT'            AS 'TaxName',
   SUM(TaxAmount)       AS 'Tax'
 FROM
   PMT_InvoiceTaxAttribute
 WHERE 
   InvoiceID = 100   
   AND TaxAttributeName LIKE '%VAT%'
```

This Query gives the Output as follows:

```
      TaxName                     Tax
   -------------              -----------
  CENTRAL EXCISE DUTY             15000
        CST                       NULL
        VAT                       NULL
```

Here, I don't want to display the CST and VAT since it has null value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using SQL Server, you can simplify it somewhat using a common table expression and just eliminate the rows you don't want using `HAVING` at the end;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN TaxAttributeName LIKE '%CST%' THEN 'CST' 
         WHEN TaxAttributeName LIKE '%VAT%' THEN 'VAT'
         WHEN TaxAttributeName LIKE '%IBR%' THEN NULL
         ELSE 'CENTRAL EXCISE DUTY' END TaxName,
    TaxAmount Tax
  FROM PMT_InvoiceTaxAttribute
  WHERE InvoiceID = 100
)
SELECT TaxName, SUM(Tax) Tax FROM cte
GROUP BY TaxName
HAVING TaxName IS NOT NULL AND SUM(Tax) IS NOT NULL
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7f3b/3).

EDIT: Just for completeness, the minimally intrusive way to fix your existing query is to wrap it in another select that removes the rows you're not interested in;

```
SELECT * FROM (
    ...your query here...
) a_dummy_name_is_required_here
WHERE Tax IS NOT NULL;
```

Note the slight difference of the first query against the original query, if a row is set to `CSTVAT`, the original query will count it as both `CST` and `VAT`, while the first query with the CTE will count it as `CST` only. I suspect they're not overlapping, but I thought I'd mention it to be sure.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT     
   'CENTRAL EXCISE DUTY'    AS 'TaxName',
   SUM(TaxAmount)       AS 'Tax'
 FROM
   PMT_InvoiceTaxAttribute
 WHERE 
   InvoiceID = 100 
   AND TaxAttributeName NOT LIKE '%IBR%' 
   AND TaxAttributeName NOT LIKE '%CST%' 
   AND TaxAttributeName NOT LIKE '%VAT%'
 UNION
 SELECT
   'CST'            AS 'TaxName',
   SUM(TaxAmount)       AS 'Tax'
 FROM
   PMT_InvoiceTaxAttribute
 WHERE 
   InvoiceID = 100   
   AND TaxAttributeName LIKE '%CST%'
 UNION
 SELECT
   'VAT'            AS 'TaxName',
   SUM(TaxAmount)       AS 'Tax'
 FROM
   PMT_InvoiceTaxAttribute
 WHERE 
   InvoiceID = 100   
   AND TaxAttributeName LIKE '%VAT%') as SomeName
WHERE TAX is NOT NULL
```

Comment: Please note that `UNION` is unnecessary in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one -

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
     SELECT
           TaxName = 'CENTRAL EXCISE DUTY'
         , Tax = SUM(TaxAmount)
     FROM PMT_InvoiceTaxAttribute
     WHERE InvoiceID = 100
          AND TaxAttributeName NOT LIKE '%IBR%'
          AND TaxAttributeName NOT LIKE '%CST%'
          AND TaxAttributeName NOT LIKE '%VAT%'

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
            TaxName = 
                    CASE WHEN TaxAttributeName LIKE '%CST%'
                              THEN 'CST' 
                              ELSE 'VAT' 
                    END
          , Tax = SUM(TaxAmount)
     FROM PMT_InvoiceTaxAttribute
     WHERE InvoiceID = 100
          AND ( 
                 TaxAttributeName LIKE '%CST%' 
               OR 
                 TaxAttributeName LIKE '%VAT%'  
          )
) t
WHERE Tax IS NOT NULL
```

Or try this -

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
     SELECT TaxAttributeName, TaxAmount 
     FROM PMT_InvoiceTaxAttribute
     WHERE InvoiceID = 100
)
SELECT *
FROM
(
     SELECT 
            TaxName = 'CENTRAL EXCISE DUTY'
          , Tax = SUM(TaxAmount)
     FROM cte
     WHERE NOT EXISTS(
         SELECT 1
         FROM (VALUES ('IBR'), ('CST'), ('VAT')) c(filter)  
         WHERE TaxAttributeName LIKE '%' + filter + '%'
     )

     UNION ALL

     SELECT 
            TaxName = 
                    CASE WHEN TaxAttributeName LIKE '%CST%'
                              THEN 'CST' 
                              ELSE 'VAT' 
                    END
          , Tax = SUM(TaxAmount)
     FROM cte
     WHERE ( 
                 TaxAttributeName LIKE '%CST%' 
               OR 
                 TaxAttributeName LIKE '%VAT%'  
          )
) t
WHERE Tax IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I think your second query is missing a `GROUP BY CASE ... END` on the latter part of the union. At least I can't make it work as is :)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to avoid the UNIONS.

```
select
    Case 
        When TaxAttributeName LIKE '%CST%' Then 'CST'
        When TaxAttributeName LIKE '%VAT%' Then 'VAT'
        Else 'CENTRAL EXCISE DUTY'
    End 'TaxName',
    SUM(TaxAmount) as 'Tax'
From 
    PMT_InvoiceTaxAttribute
Where
    InvoiceID = 100
    AND TaxAttributeName not like '%IBR%'
Group By
    Case 
        When TaxAttributeName LIKE '%CST%' Then 'CST'
        When TaxAttributeName LIKE '%VAT%' Then 'VAT'
        Else 'CENTRAL EXCISE DUTY'
    End
```

Although I like Joachim's CTE a little better.  Maybe...

```
with TaxCTE as (
    select
        InvoiceID,
        Case When TaxAttributeName LIKE '%CST%' Then 'CST'
             When TaxAttributeName LIKE '%VAT%' Then 'VAT'
             Else 'CENTRAL EXCISE DUTY'
        End 'TaxName',
        TaxAmount
    From PMT_InvoiceTaxAttribute
    where TaxAttributeName not like '%IBR%')
select TaxName, SUM(TaxAmount) Tax 
from TaxCTE 
where InvoiceId = 100
group by TaxName
```